# How do I pick a string from a larger string within an array and group them with name?

Tags: php

I have an array in php script.

```
 $carstable = array(
    "tbl_Volvo_01_05_16",
    "tbl_Volvo_02_05_16",
    "tbl_Volvo_03_05_16",
    "tbl_Volvo_04_05_16",
    "tbl_BMW_01_05_16",
    "tbl_BMW_02_05_16",
    "tbl_BMW_03_05_16",
    "tbl_BMW_04_05_16",
    "tbl_Toyota_01_05_16",
    "tbl_Toyota_02_05_16",
    "tbl_Toyota_03_05_16",
    "tbl_Toyota_04_05_16");
```

This array is generated by the system.I want another array from it that will contain only the list of cars mentioned in the above array.
I want the array to be like :

```
$cars =array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
```

Comment: only car name and unique array values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach with `array_map` & `array_unique` & `preg_match` to enable support for different string structures:

```
<?php

$carstable = array(
    "tbl_Volvo_01_05_16",
    "tbl_Volvo_02_05_16",
    "tbl_Volvo_03_05_16",
    "tbl_Volvo_04_05_16",
    "tbl_BMW_01_05_16",
    "tbl_BMW_02_05_16",
    "tbl_BMW_03_05_16",
    "tbl_BMW_04_05_16",
    "tbl_Toyota_01_05_16",
    "tbl_Toyota_02_05_16",
    "tbl_Toyota_03_05_16",
    "tbl_Toyota_04_05_16"
);

$cars = array_map(function($v){
    preg_match("/tbl_([^_]+)/", $v, $t);
    return $t[1];
}, $carstable);

$cars = array_unique($cars);

var_dump($cars);
```

output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Volvo"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "BMW"
  [8]=>
  string(6) "Toyota"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach and explode the value with `_` and store them into final array. now apply array_unique for getting unique array values.

```
$carstable = array(
    "tbl_Volvo_01_05_16",
    "tbl_Volvo_02_05_16",
    "tbl_Volvo_03_05_16",
    "tbl_Volvo_04_05_16",
    "tbl_BMW_01_05_16",
    "tbl_BMW_02_05_16",
    "tbl_BMW_03_05_16",
    "tbl_BMW_04_05_16",
    "tbl_Toyota_01_05_16",
    "tbl_Toyota_02_05_16",
    "tbl_Toyota_03_05_16",
    "tbl_Toyota_04_05_16"
);

$final = array();
foreach($carstable as $val){
    $tmp = explode("_", $val);
    $final[] = $tmp[1]; 
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_values(array_unique($final)));
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Volvo
    [1] => BMW
    [2] => Toyota
)
```

Comment: What will happen with `Alfa_Romeo` btw?

Comment: Sorry,  I did't catch you.

Comment: @u_mulder See my answer for that.

Comment: @u_mulder, Where it is in OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do something like below:

```
<?php
$carstable = array(
    "tbl_Volvo_01_05_16",
    "tbl_Volvo_02_05_16",
    "tbl_Volvo_03_05_16",
    "tbl_Volvo_04_05_16",
    "tbl_BMW_01_05_16",
    "tbl_BMW_02_05_16",
    "tbl_BMW_03_05_16",
    "tbl_BMW_04_05_16",
    "tbl_Toyota_01_05_16",
    "tbl_Toyota_02_05_16",
    "tbl_Toyota_03_05_16",
    "tbl_Toyota_04_05_16");

//$cars =array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");

$cars = array();
foreach( $carstable as $carinfo ) {
    $tokens = explode( '_', $carinfo );
    $cars[] = $tokens[1];
}
$cars = array_unique( $cars );

print_r($cars);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

loop through the array and explode it with "_"

```
<?php
$carstable = array(
    "tbl_Volvo_01_05_16",
    "tbl_Volvo_02_05_16",
    "tbl_Volvo_03_05_16",
    "tbl_Volvo_04_05_16",
    "tbl_BMW_01_05_16",
    "tbl_BMW_02_05_16",
    "tbl_BMW_03_05_16",
    "tbl_BMW_04_05_16",
    "tbl_Toyota_01_05_16",
    "tbl_Toyota_02_05_16",
    "tbl_Toyota_03_05_16",
    "tbl_Toyota_04_05_16");
$newArray = array();
foreach ($carstable as $value) {
  $carArray = explode('_',$value);
  if (isset($carArray[1])) {
    $newArray[] = $carArray[1];
  }  
}
print_r(array_unique($newArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

A short snippet, works with Alfa Romeo too.

```
$carstable = array(
    "tbl_Volvo_01_05_16",
    "tbl_Volvo_02_05_16",
    "tbl_Volvo_03_05_16",
    "tbl_Volvo_04_05_16",
    "tbl_BMW_01_05_16",
    "tbl_BMW_02_05_16",
    "tbl_BMW_03_05_16",
    "tbl_BMW_04_05_16",
    "tbl_Toyota_01_05_16",
    "tbl_Toyota_02_05_16",
    "tbl_Toyota_03_05_16",
    "tbl_Toyota_04_05_16",
    "tbl_Alfa_Romeo_04_05_16",
);

$result = array_unique(array_map(function($row) { 
    $a = explode('_', $row);
    return array_slice($a, 1, sizeof($a)-4);
}, $carstable));
```

Will result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Volvo
    [1] => BMW
    [2] => Toyota
    [3] => Alfa_Romeo
)
```

Comment: @FrayneKonok u_muler mentioned in another answer's comment. Naively spitting on every `_` wouldnt work on brands like that.